# Delphi XE7 code navigation problems

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

Just started to use Delphi XE7 and experiencing a terrible code navigation lags on all my big Delphi projects (when clicking some identifier with Ctrl pressed). When I click some identifier, I can see a lots of messages appearing in the IDE console, seems like it parsing all my units again and again without caching anything.

I switched off Tooltip symbol insight, Tooltip help insight, Error insight and Code templates, however it doesn't help.

Delphi 2010 works without a problem on my machine with the same projects.

Maybe you know some secret command line option to make code navigation fast again?

Comment: Some IDE lags and other problems might be resolved with IDE Fix Pack by Andreas Hausladen http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/2014/11/tools-used-to-develop-ide-fix-pack/

Comment: I agree with @MBo. Use Andreas' patches. No one should use Delphi without them. How big is the lag? In my case is never over 2 seconds.

Comment: "in the IDE console" - what do you mean by ide console?

Answer (score 0):

The Delphi compilers have indeed grown worse over the years in this aspect. If you jump from D2010 I can imagine it feels horrible.

This is especially bad when you have just switched to a new project.

One thing that helps is building your project so that all cache info is up to date. You'll notice that it is not so bad once you are in your edit/compile cycles (and after your first Ctrl-Click).

---

As an additional note, my XE2 from time to time looses its Ctrl-Click functionality, and I have to shut down/restart the IDE.